# Showing that a bounded linear function between Banach spaces $X, Y$ is compact if $\mathrm{dim}(A[X]) < \infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded linear map where $X, Y$ are Banach spaces. I am trying to understand why it "follows immediately" that if $T$'s image is finite dimensional, then $T$ is a compact operator. A hint given to me is to use Heine-Borel Theorem, that a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded in finite dimensional case. I initially thought that this task is trivial, but I've now come to realization that I have some major holes in my understanding of linear operators. Namely

(**Closedness**) I understand that a sequential closedness might be the easiest way to show that $T[X]$ is closed. If we take some Cauchy sequence $(v_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $T[X]$, we know immediately that $v_n \to v$ for some $v \in Y$ as $n\to \infty$ by completeness of $Y$. But then, I struggle to show that a preimage sequence of $(v_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is also Cauchy (or that it converges) so that I can use continuity of $T$ to juggle with the limit of $v_n$.

(**Boundedness**) While I see that the image of any bounded set, say the unit ball $B_1(0)$, is bounded under $T$, I am not really sure how to conclude from this that $T[X]$ is bounded, since surely $||v||$ can grow without a bound for $v \in X$.

I appreciate all tips, hints and help, thanks!

Comment: You seem to believe that the [definition of compacity for an operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator) is that its image is compact (which indeed is never the case, except for $T=0$). If the image $F$ is finite dimensional, then the image of the unit ball is  relatively compact (as a bounded subset of $F$), that's all.

Comment: @AnneBauval This might be a dumb question, but what if $T$ maps $X$ onto the ball $B_{1/2}(0)$? Can we conclude the same result by the fact that the scaled version of the unit ball is a bounded subset of the image $F$?

Comment: The image is never bounded, except for $T=0.$